Java - Jackson - How to deserialize the random XML as a String value of Map<String,String> then serialize it as it is
The old description was not what I wanted, here is the updated version for what I wanted.
package jackson.serialzation;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlElementWrapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlProperty;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
        System.out.println("Test 1");
        String test1 = "<Wrapper><a><b><c>3 &amp; 7 - 8 &lt; 9</c> </b></a></Wrapper>";

        Wrapper wrapper = xmlMapper.readValue(test1, Wrapper.class);
        System.out.println(wrapper.getMyMap().get("a"));
        String outputXML = xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(wrapper);
        System.out.println(outputXML);

        System.out.println("-----------------");

        System.out.println("Test 2");
        String test2 ="<Wrapper><a><![CDATA[<b><c>3 &amp; 7 - 8 &lt; 9</c> </b>]]></a></Wrapper>";

        wrapper = xmlMapper.readValue(test2, Wrapper.class);
        System.out.println(wrapper.getMyMap().get("a"));
        outputXML = xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(wrapper);
        System.out.println(outputXML);
    }
}

class Wrapper {
    private Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<>();

   @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, String> getMyMap() {
        return myMap;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "myMap")
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    public void addToMap(String key, String value) {
        this.myMap.put(key, value);
    }
}

I wanted to read any child element of element <a> as String value of the key a of myMap in Wrapper class.
Output from the above code is:
Test 1

Test 1

<Wrapper><a></a></Wrapper>
-----------------
Test 2
<b><c>3 &amp; 7 - 8 &lt; 9</c> </b>
<Wrapper><a>&lt;b>&lt;c>3 &amp;amp; 7 - 8 &amp;lt; 9&lt;/c> &lt;/b></a></Wrapper>

Ideally, I hoped that Jackson has some annotation which allows this behavior in Test 1 (however, it just prints empty for value of key a which is not what I wanted).
Then, I tried with Test 2 with wrap CDATA around <b>...</b> so Jackson can deserialize <b>...</b> just as it is as String value. But when serializing wrapper object to String, it returns unwanted output to me.
It should be:
<Wrapper><a><b><c>3 &amp; 7 - 8 &lt; 9</c> </b></a></Wrapper>
NOT <Wrapper><a>&lt;b>&lt;c>3 &amp;amp; 7 - 8 &amp;lt; 9&lt;/c> &lt;/b></a></Wrapper>
So if Jackson could deserialize the String in Test 1, then it could serialize to a string exactly like String test1 is what I wanted to have.

This is standard XML. Why do you not want to unescape it? If you expect to read &lt;, it should be written &amp;lt; in the first place.

If you also have access to the XML, you can put 3 &lt; 7 into a CDATA: <X><!--[CDATA[3 < 7]]--></X>. You can also write a custom deserialiser that unescapes the XML special characters (&lt; to <).

Quite. 3 &lt; 7 is the XML representation of the string 3 < 7, so that's the string you're going to get.

@GaëlJ I wanted to have it as 3 &lt; 7 as it is provided, because later I will need to combine these values from the map and serialize them to a XML string again. So 3 < 7 (more special characters as well) will be invalid XML.

@Bademeister The client will not provide the CDATA wrapping for that value 3 &lt;7, so unfortunate I cannot do anything.

If you use XML tooling and APIs to construct your XML, then it will encode the < properly and won't be a problem. You are trying to solve your issue the wrong way.

There is no answer for this question by using Jackson, so in the end in order to keep 3 &lt; 7 as it is, I needed to modify client to post XML wrapped in <!CDATA[[3 &lt; 7]]>, then Jackson will not convert that to 3 < 7 (which is not the wanted behavior).

No. Just no. Just accept that 3 < 7 is correct. If your serialization afterwards cannot deal with that, fix your serialization.

@Sören no, <a>3 <7</a> is NOT valid XML, input must be <!CDATA[[3 &lt; 7]]> so Jackson will keep it as it is when deserializing.

@BằngRikimaru You need to create a custom deserialiser that is called at element level and unescapes the XML special characters (&lt; to <).

@Bademeister I don't want to escape that &lt; to <, I just wanted to keep as-is  &lt; no <, both when deserializing / serializing with Jackson. But no, Jackson does not want that simple feature.

I never said it was.

Then do < to &lt; with a custom deserialiser. That's what something like this is for!

@Sören and I never wanted that 3 < 7, so don't say just accept anything which I don't want.

@Bademeister 3 &lt; 7 is just a simple example I gave to you. it can actually have a nested XML string with random structure under <a> <XML>...</XML> </a>.
Bottom line, I don't think we understand each other, so thanks for all comments, but this really doesn't help my issue.

Ok, you don't want the correct solution. You don't say why you don't want it. Too bad, I can't help you.

@Sören Just see may previous comment to Bademeister which will reply to you recent comment.

Ok, one of your values is itself valid XML. So what? That's not a problem, if you use proper serialization. Either you belief what people are telling you, or you don't. I don't care. Don't @ me again.
